# Why my flywaydb runs with incorrect order?

Tags: java, flyway

There are many lower versions before 3.94,but is runs skipped 3.1-3.93 and start from 3.94 ... (version 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.1 is before 3.1 in another module)

I have no idea to solve this error..The same code in another colleague's IDE running normally.

```
2019-04-16 11:49:35.795  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 1.1 - 20190222-init
2019-04-16 11:49:35.815  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_dict' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:35.846  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_menu' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:35.873  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_operate' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:35.900  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_role' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:35.921  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_role_menu' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:35.942  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_role_operate' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.023  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_operate_log' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.060  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_event_hook' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.089  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.gjj_notice' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.126  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.gjj_notice_type' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.161  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 1.2 - 20190222-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.215  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 1.3 - 20190312-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.217  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown table 'mydb.mydb_heng_i18n' (SQL State: 42S02 - Error Code: 1051)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.256  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 1.4 - 20190313-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.269  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 2.1 - 20190311-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.297  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 3.92 - 20190401-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.312  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 3.93 - 20190402-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.325  INFO 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migrating schema `mydb` to version 3.94 - 20190402-init
2019-04-16 11:49:36.329  WARN 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.c.internal.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate    : DB: Unknown column 'i18n_nid' in 'field list' (SQL State: 42S22 - Error Code: 1054)
2019-04-16 11:49:36.330 ERROR 6408 --- [           main] [] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Migration of schema `mydb` to version 3.94 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
```

Comment: It looks like the migration version 3.92, 3.93, 3.94 runs succesfully.

Comment: I'm sorry to change question to [it runs skipped 3.1-3.91 and start from 3.92]...

Comment: try first of all to clean up your database: `mvn flyway:clean`, then `mvn flyway:migrate`

Comment: also, please add info in your question, executing next commands: `mvn: flyway:info` and `mvn flyway:validate`.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Facing a similar issue now where my order of execution is `1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.0, 1.0.3`